# How to categorize images in the drawable folder?

Tags: android

I have a lot of images and I want to classify them in the drawable folder in Android Studio for easy access, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. The only way to sort your drawable resources is by renaming them, usually with prefixes (i.e. `ic_` for icons).

Comment: Thanks but suppose we have 1000 images, is it logical to put them all into the drawable folder?

Comment: You could always consider storing your images in assets (where you would have complete control over the folder structure) rather than /res/drawable, but it's not recommended because it will add a lot of boilerplate to your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment this is a good idea with the use InputStream ims = getAssets().open(path);
 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null); but as you said it slows down the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put them in folders. However, you can control the name of them to find them easier. For example, if I have buttons coded with shapes, etc, I will name these button_name. This way, it all of my buttons are there for me to view. If I have a few minutes in a certain activity, I will do something like results_, and then all of my results images are there. Hopefully they makes sense and helps.

Comment: That's right, but suppose we have so many resources, In this case is it logical to put them all into the only one drawable folder?